# Recurring payment payflow error response "Invalid tender"

Tags: paypal

I am trying to create recurring profile and I get his log output with error

```
   [METHOD] => CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
                [SUBSCRIBERNAME] => testuser
                [PROFILESTARTDATE] => 2014-05-14T16:01:36-04:00
                [DESC] => Monthly Payment for Package:Package 4
                [MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS] => 1
                [AUTOBILLOUTAMT] => NoAutoBill
                [TRIALBILLINGPERIOD] => Month
                [TRIALBILLINGFREQUENCY] => 1
                [TRIALTOTALBILLINGCYCLES] => 1
                [TRIALAMT] => 129.00
                [BILLINGPERIOD] => Month
                [BILLINGFREQUENCY] => 12
                [TOTALBILLINGCYCLES] => 0
                [AMT] => 129.00
                [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
                [CREDITCARDTYPE] => MasterCard
                [ACCT] => 5473878247587096
                [EXPDATE] => 012015
                [CVV2] => 962
                [STARTDATE] => 
                [ISSUENUMBER] => 
                [FIRSTNAME] => John
                [LASTNAME] => Doe
                [STREET] => 1324 Adams Street
                [CITY] => Omaha
                [STATE] => AL
                [COUNTRYCODE] => US
                [ZIP] => 68138
                [PHONENUM] => 1402935200
                [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_L_ITEMCATEGORY0] => Digital
                [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_L_NAME0] => Package 4
                [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_L_DESC0] => test package
                [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_L_AMT0] => 129.00
                [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_L_NUMBER0] => 4
            [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_L_QTY0] => 3500


RESULT=2&PNREF=A7X06BD15AD4&RESPMSG=Invalid tender.
```

The [description](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/result_values_for_transaction_declines_or_errors.htm) suggests that merchant account does not support said credit card.But in my manager.paypal.com account I see visa/master and other credit cards are supported. I tried with visa/master , for both I get same error. May be I missing something, please help out.
I have paypal payments advanced subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe you're signed up for Payments Pro, but not for [Recurring Payments](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/general/ProRecurringPayments-outside), which is an add-on feature.

Comment: thanks , in my manager.payapl.com account I see Recurring enabled with limited Payflow SDK support.Current subscription is Payments Advanced : https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-advanced. Now don't ask I understand completely these SDKS. They are beyond comprehension in sane way.

Comment: OK, yeah, payments advanced isn't going to let you process cards directly with CRPP.  Payments Advanced uses iFrames and embeds the checkout forms into your site so that you're not actually handling any credit card data.  You'll need the full Pro in order to use CRPP, and the new version of Pro actually uses PayFlow, so you'll want to make sure you know which version you're on so you don't build on the wrong platform.  CRPP will require the old "Website Payments Pro 3.0" where-as the new version of Payments Pro uses PayFlow instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to the PayPal PayFlow API documentation, receiving a result with the status "2" means:

> Invalid tender type. Your merchant bank account does not support the
>   following credit card type that was submitted.

Source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#result-values-and-respmsg-text